# Search an array to find ObjectB.property that matches ObjectA.property

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, compare

I have 2 Arrays filled with objects, both objects have the same property teamID, every time i tap the screen an object from TeamObject is activated, i need to search for the matching teamID in ExtraTeamInfoObject:

Here's what i got so far, but not working:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"teamDetailsSeg"]){

        TeamDetailsTableViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        long row = [myIndexPath row];

        TeamObject *item = [tableData objectAtIndex:row];
    ExtraTeamInfoObject *item2 = _allInfo[row];

    ExtraTeamInfoObject *searchingObject;

    for (int i = 0; i < _allInfo.count && searchingObject; i++){

        for (ExtraTeamInfoObject *co in _allInfo[i]) {

            if (co.teamID == item.teamID) {

                searchingObject = item2;

                break;
                }
                }
                }


        detailViewController.teamDetailModel = item2;

        NSLog(@" Object %@", item.teamID);
        NSLog(@" Extra  %@", item2.teamID);

        }
}
```

Somehow this didn't crash my app and it works, but looking at the bottom 2 NSLog prints, this comes out:

2014-02-12 10:51:26.255  Object 531
2014-02-12 10:51:26.255  Extra  539

Meaning that it's not searching for the right object at all. Anyone knows a fix for this? Thank you.

Comment: What are the objects in your second array ? If they are custom classes, using NSPredicates would be much easier than iteration.

Comment: yes both are custom classes, can you show me a sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `for` loops, I would prefer using NSPredicate thanks to KVC goodness:

```
ExtraTeamInfoObject *searchingObject;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"teamID == %@", item.teamID];
NSArray *result = [_allInfo filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

if (results.count) {
    searchingObject = [results firstObject];
}
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to target variable, your code works beautifully, thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you are enumerating a single object when you do:

```
for (ExtraTeamInfoObject *co in _allInfo[i])
```

Should it not be:

```
for (ExtraTeamInfoObject *co in _allInfo)
```

Comment: i changed that but it's still not matching the ids

Comment: You are also using detailViewController.teamDetailModel = item2; where I think it should be detailViewController.teamDetailModel = searchingObject;.

However, as others have mentioned, a predicate would probably be the better option.